# Hyper-V to Physical

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

How do I go about converting a Hyper-v VM to a physical hard drive. I created a Windows 10 vm and now want to create a physical system out of it. I attached a secondary hard drive on the host system and would like to copy the image to the secondary drive. Then take that drive and install it on another physical system. The other physical system has the same model hardware as the guest. The image is larger than 4.7 GB and does not fit onto a DVD so I not looking for iso solution. Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering if you couldn't boot that VM off a Macrium Reflect rescue image. Then create an image of the VM, then restore it to a physical machine. You've got me intrigued and now I wanna try it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend avoiding doing that. V2P is pretty possible but not always been successful. However, you can convert VM to the Physical Machine using this [article](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/virtual-to-physical-conversions-v2p/) with an image of the current VM or even try to simply robocopy/network copy all needed files from the VM to Physical Machine